# How to assign content of a file to a string variable in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: string, copy, progress-4gl, openedge

Assigning content of a huge file around 80 KB to a string variable

```
copy-lob from file "E:\edifact\test\22685.EDI" to text-memptr.
v-edistring  = get-string(text-memptr,1).
```

> shows error attempt to exceed maximum size of character variable.

Comment: Currently I am running in windows , can you please mention what code I should add ?

Comment: v-edistring needs to be a LONGCHAR, not a regular CHARACTER string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need the mempointer? Otherwise you can just COPY-LOB into a LONGCHAR directly.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cString AS LONGCHAR   NO-UNDO.

COPY-LOB FROM FILE "E:\edifact\test\PFCONCEPT22685.EDI" TO cString.
```